# Task :shared:linkDebugFrameworkIos FAILED

Tags: ios, kotlin, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm trying to play with Kotlin Multiplatform and can't get it compiled for an iOS project.
My build.gradle.kt file:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    // kotlin("native.cocoapods") //version "1.5.10"
    id("co.touchlab.native.cocoapods")
    id("kotlinx-serialization")
}

kotlin {
    // ios()
    // Revert to just ios() when gradle plugin can properly resolve it
    val onPhone = System.getenv("SDK_NAME")?.startsWith("iphoneos") ?: false
    if (onPhone) {
        iosArm64("ios")
    } else {
        iosX64("ios")
    }

    version = "1.1"

    sourceSets { ... }

    cocoapodsext {
        summary = "Common library for the KaMP starter kit"
        homepage = "https://github.com/touchlab/KaMPKit"
        // isStatic = false
        framework {
            isStatic = false
            transitiveExport = true
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to use both `co.touchlab.native.cocoapods` and `native.cocoapods` plugins and I always get the same error for any way I choose.

The error:

```
> Task :kotlin-api-client:compileKotlinIosX64 UP-TO-DATE
> Task :shared:generateIosMainKaMPKitDbInterface UP-TO-DATE
> Task :shared:compileKotlinIos UP-TO-DATE
> Task :shared:linkDebugFrameworkIos FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':shared:linkDebugFrameworkIos'.
> 'void org.jetbrains.kotlin.konan.target.Distribution.<init>(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.String, java.util.Map, int, kotlin.jvm.internal.DefaultConstructorMarker)'
```

What could be wrong? Any ideas at least where to look at?

Comment: Don't use ours (touchlab). We're deprecating that soon, if not already. We're using the standard Jetbrains/Kotlin one.

Comment: For figuring out the Jetbrains/Kotlin version of cocoapods, can you post more about the error?

Comment: @KevinGalligan it doesn't matter what I'm using, I get the same error for both ways. 
KMM plugin - 0.2.6(202-1.5.10) version, Kotlin - 202-1.5.0

Comment: If I had more info, I definitely would share it here, everything what I get is this weird error (updated the question a bit)

Comment: @alex_izh could you run the task with `--stacktrace`?

Comment: Okay, thank you guys, epically @KevinGalligan. The problem was in `classpath`, I didn't remove it when tried to use `native.cocoapods`. All what I needed to do is just to remove `classpath` with Touchlab's library